# Get two histograms plotted over eachother to have the same width bins

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, histogram

I have two histograms that ive plotted overeachother. Sample 1 has 100 objects and sample 2 has 6000 objects, but i've normalised them such that I can compare them. However is there a way to get it so both the histograms have the same width bins.

Code below:

```
bins=100
plt.hist(change_sample1, bins=bins, color='blue', edgecolor='black', label='Sample1', density=True)
plt.hist(change_sample2, bins=bins, color='red', edgecolor='black', label='Sample2', density=True) 
plt.xlabel('Change in sample size')
plt.ylabel('Proportion origional sample')
plt.xlim(-1, 1)
plt.title('Distribution of change in sample size')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

So I'd like both histograms to have the same bin edges and widths, and I can totally change the number of bins each graph has, thats fine. Is there any way to do this?

[image]

Comment: If you force them to have the same range, the bins should have the same width, see https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hist.html

Comment: As a tip, for sample2 you could add the `alpha` keyword to `plt.hist`. `alpha` less than 1 makes the bars translucent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `range` argument of `plt.hist`. In this case, given your x-range you could use `plt.hist(change_sample1, bins=bins, range=(-1, 1), ...)`. And then use the same range for `change_sample2`.